# Converting 8Bit to True 16Bit?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am a 3D artist and I use a lot of textures for bump mapping etc...

If I take a regular 8bit black and white jpg image and add a blur to it with PS set to 16bit. Am I Gaining information? (I realize my image will be blurry, and I will lose sharpness detail) but will I GAIN pixel information with the blur gradients that are created?

So if I saved it out as Tiff, EXR, etc.. in 16bit, would it be a true 16bit image?

EDIT:

Added some test (have no idea if this was a fair comparision).
Clearly converting an 8 bit to 16bit is better. So something is being added. 
[image]

Comment: You have the same amount of information, but it's just blurred more. Sort of the difference between "Yes" and "yeeee-aaa---hhhh". Photoshop cannot create *new* information. As to your "so...": yeaaa--aa-ah ... if you save it as such, then why shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this: [What's the point of capturing 14 bit images and editing on 8 bit monitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH8lb.png)

[image]

In this case, yes and no... it depends.

No, because your initial 8-bit image will have the same gaps as image B, regardless that you transform it into a 16-bit image. The information will not change.

[image]

The difference will be noticeable if you "invent" new in between information, for example, **smudging the image**. In this scenario, you will have new information filling the space you prepared by transforming the image into 16 bits.

[image]

But this new information will not be yet noticeable until you apply a similar transformation as image C and D on my original image.

---

But if your render can be saved as 16 bits, sure, save it as such. Some render engines generate an image of more than a 24 bits (RGB) file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would be exporting OUT of PS as a 16bit TIFF to import INTO a 3D program to use as height information. So to be clear I AM making NEW information by using the blur which is essentially "filling in the gaps". So that leads me to wonder if I can use the frequency separation technique to have a mostly 16bit TIFF converted from 8bit image, to fill in the gaps? sorry if that is confusing.

Comment: Not confusing at all... I would say... try it. I am not sure if your 3D program will detect it. It is probably better that you refine your own workflow.